# Gnome - Kill X Windows

Tags: linux, gnome, x-windows, kill

I just installed Arch Linux with Gnome and gdm is set to boot into gnome as soon as it boots.
But I realized that the barebone gnome package that I installed doesn't include a terminal or a text editor so I can't install anything further or modify the rc.conf file to make it boot without gdm.

Is there a way for me to kill x from the Gnome interface?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Esc keys ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get to a virtual terminal.  Or just install a text editor.